# Show alphabet letters on keyboard after pressing space

Tags: react-native

In some apps like Google maps or Apple Maps, when you want to search for an address, if you go to the numbers section and type a comma and then type a `space`, it goes back to the alphabet section on the keyboard. So you will not need to change the keyboard by yourself. How can we implement the same behavior in `react-native` apps?

Also, native `Java` and `Swift` solutions are welcome.

Before typing `space`:

[image: Before typing space]

After typing `space`:

[image: Before typing space]